# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection warning when axios call fails

Tags: react-native, promise

Every time if there is a `504` or `404` from an API call that I make I get the warning:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 12):
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: rej

Here is how I've coded:

```
function myFunction() {

    const fullURL = 'URL_THAT_I_HIT'
    const data = { "SOME_ID": ID_VALUE, }

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        try {
            axios.post(fullURL, data).then((response) => {
                res(response.data)
            }).catch((error) => {
                rej(error)
                alert(error)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            rej(error)
            alert(error)
        }
    })
}
```

As per my understanding, I'm handling the `rej` and I've even double wrapped it so that I can throw rejection. Here is my code below where I'm calling `myFunction`

```
     function fetchMyFunctionCall() {
        if (res === undefined) {
            alert("The call rejected")
        } else {
            console.log(res)
        }
    }
```

It shows the error message but I still see the warning. So, how do I handle the rejection properly in `fetchMyFunctionCall`?

Comment: Where have you defined the variable rej? Are you sure its the same name and you’re importing it correctly?

Comment: @Ajay my bad I didn't copy that part of the code. I've updated my questions now you can see where I've defined the variable `rej`. I'm returning a `Promise`.

Comment: probably remove the try/catch? use either try/catch or .catch(err), not both. If you want to move the error up, then just do `throw error` in the catch block. Also, axio itself is already a promise so you don't need to create `new Promise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to repro your error for the undefined variable but I think you can simplify your code like below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const fullURL = 'URL_THAT_I_HIT'
  const data = {
    "SOME_ID": ID_VALUE,
  }

  return axios.post(fullURL, data).then((response) => {
    return response.data
  });
}

myFunction().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Axios itself returns a promise so no need of returning one explicitly.

Comment: The reason why I use `Promise` as there are some API calls that take longer in the app I'm building. For example, there are times when I have to call one API and then use the data in that call I have to send multiple calls to different APIs and I've used `Promise All` to handle that. The approach you shared is simple and easy to understand but will it work in a case like the one I mentioned? If not then can you update your answer to included a `Promise`?